# How to get an XML value from FLEX

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, adobe

i have the following Problem - first of all i'm totally new to Flex. I was search through about 20 Websites but haven't found a Solution:

I have xml file like that:

```
<xml>
   <settings>
      <mainurl>http://localhost/website/</mainurl>
      <adminurl>http://localhost/website/admin</adminurl>
   </settings>
</xml>
```

Now i have

```
<mx:Model id="xmlfile" source="conf/config.xml">
```

That works fine for my DataGrid, but in the

```
<mx:Script></mx:Script>
```

section i have a function:

```
private function loadConf():void
{
   var admURL:String = xmlfile.setting.mainurl;
}
```

But it does not work?!?!

How to get it working? As i told before, i have read a lot of Tutorials and Adobe Examples but always found a way working with it on DataGrids and Stuff like that - that ways all work for me, but i can't get the above working.

Hope you can help.

Thx so much,
Sascha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
xmlfile.setting.mainurl
```

should be

```
xmlfile.settings.mainurl
```

Comment: that was not the problem!!! it was just a mistake of mine!

if i do an Alert.show(admURL,'Info') - nothing is shown. Checked the URL and everything!

I have tested to show the URL in my DataGrid to see if i have any mitstakes - nothing! In the DataGrid it is shown correctly!

Anyone has another idea? May i create an ArrayCollection? Isn't it possible to directly access?

Comment: okay, sorry for that - had a spelling mistake somewhere else.